# My webpage is not being resized correctly when changing the size of the window

Tags: html, css, resize

I am trying to make a website for a basic portfolio where all the information is in the middle of the page instead of using the full width. However, when resizing the window the border of the header and the rest of the body don't match up so it looks odd. Also I have outlined the main body part with a white border but would like to know how to extend that border so it touches the top of the footer sections, thanks for any help.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(238, 11, 11, 0.705);
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
}

header li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header ul {
  margin-left: 40.48%;
  max-width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header h1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.max-width {
  margin-left: 15%;
  max-width: 70.4%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(238, 11, 11, 0.705);
  width: 100%;
}

footer h4,
footer p {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.flexbox {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flexbox img {
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Rijul</h1>
  <ul>
    <nav>
      <li><a href=homepage.html>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=skills&achievments.html>Skills and Achievments</a></li>
      <li><a href=portfolio.html>Portfolio</a></li>
      <!-- Put Education Qualification and Experience into portfolio -->
      <li><a href=#Blog>Blog Page</a></li>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</header>

<section class="max-width">
  <section id="Home">
    <h2>About Me:</h2>
    <h2>I'm Rijul, a<br>Computer Science<br>Student</h2>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <p>I am a first year undergrad student.</p>
      <img src="images/rij.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
<footer>
  <section id="Contact">
    <h4>Contact Details:</h4>
    <p>Phone Number: </p>
    <p>Email: </p>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(238, 11, 11, 0.705);
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  height: 25vh;
}

header li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header ul {
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

header h1 {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.max-width {
  margin-left: 15%;
  max-width: 70.4%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 50vh;
}

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(238, 11, 11, 0.705);
  width: 100%;
  height: 24.7vh;
}

footer h4,
footer p {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.flexbox {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.flexbox img {
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Rijul</h1>
  <ul>
    <nav>
      <li><a href=homepage.html>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href=skills&achievments.html>Skills and Achievments</a></li>
      <li><a href=portfolio.html>Portfolio</a></li>
      <!-- Put Education Qualification and Experience into portfolio -->
      <li><a href=#Blog>Blog Page</a></li>
    </nav>
  </ul>
</header>

<section class="max-width">
  <section id="Home">
    <h2>About Me:</h2>
    <h2>I'm Rijul, a<br>Computer Science<br>Student</h2>
    <div class="flexbox">
      <p>I am a first year undergrad student.</p>
      <img src="images/rij.jpg">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
<footer>
  <section id="Contact">
    <h4>Contact Details:</h4>
    <p>Phone Number: </p>
    <p>Email: </p>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to work. The page looks different as is still unresizable at least when in connection with the header thank you though!